# Show that if $(ς_n)$ is a sequence of partitions whose size tends to $0$, the variation along $ς_n$ tends to the total variation

Tags: real-analysis, bounded-variation

Let $b>a\ge0$, $$\mathfrak T_{[a,\:b]}:=\left\{\left(t_0,\ldots,t_k\right):k\in\mathbb N\text{ and }a=t_0<\cdots<t_k=b\right\}$$ and $$\left|\varsigma\right|:=\max_{1\le i\le k}\left(t_i-t_{i-1}\right)\;\;\;\text{for }\varsigma=\left(t_0,\ldots,t_k\right)\in\mathfrak T_{[a,\:b]}\;.$$ Moreover, let $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$, $$V_\varsigma(f):=\sum_{i=1}^k\left|f(t_i)-f(t_{i-1})\right|\;\;\;\text{for }\varsigma=\left(t_0,\ldots,t_k\right)\in\mathfrak T_{[a,\:b]}$$ and $$V_{[a,\:b]}(f):=\sup_{\varsigma\in\mathfrak T_{[a,\:b]}}V_\varsigma(f)\;.$$

> Now, assume $V_{[a,\:b]}(f)<\infty$ and $f$ is continuous. Let $(\varsigma_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq\mathfrak T_{[a,\:b]}$ with $$\left|\varsigma_n\right|\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0\;.\tag1$$ I want to show that $$V_{\varsigma_n}(f)\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}V_{[a,\:b]}(f)\tag2\;.$$

By definition, $$V_{\varsigma_n}(f)\le V_{[a,\:b]}(f)\;\;\;\text{for all }n\in\mathbb N\;.\tag3$$ Assume that $(2)$ doesn't hold. Then there is an $\varepsilon>0$ with $$\forall N\in\mathbb N:\exists n\ge N:V_{\varsigma_n}(f)\le V_{[a,\:b]}(f)-\varepsilon\tag4\;.$$ Moreover, by definition of the supremum, there is a $\varsigma\in\mathfrak T_{[a,\:b]}$ with $$V_{[a,\:b]}(f)-\varepsilon<V_\varsigma(f)\tag5\;.$$

Now, I don't know how I need to proceed. Clearly $|f(a)-f(b)|\le|f(a)-f(t)|+|f(t)-f(b)|$ for all $t\in[a,b]$ and hence $V_\varsigma(f)\le V_{\varsigma\cup\varsigma_n}(f)$, but I don't know how I could use this to obtain a contradiction. So, how can we proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\varsigma = (x_0, x_1, \dotsc, x_m) \in \mathfrak{T}_{[a,b]}$ and $\varepsilon > 0$.

By the uniform continuity of $f$, choose $0 < \eta < \frac{1}{2} \min \{ x_k - x_{k-1} : 1 \leqslant k \leqslant m\}$ such that $\lvert f(x) - f(y)\rvert \leqslant \frac{\varepsilon}{2m}$ whenever $\lvert x-y\rvert \leqslant \eta$.

For $\pi = (t_0,t_1,\dotsc,t_r) \in \mathfrak{T}_{[a,b]}$ with $\lvert \pi\rvert < \eta$, let $\ell_{\mu} = \max \{ t_{\rho} : t_{\rho} \leqslant x_{\mu}\}$ and $u_{\mu} = \min \{ t_{\rho} : t_{\rho} \geqslant x_{\mu}\}$ for $0 \leqslant \mu \leqslant m$. Then

$$V_{\pi}(f) \geqslant \sum_{\mu = 1}^{m} \lvert f(\ell_{\mu}) - f(u_{\mu-1})\rvert.$$

Since $\lvert \ell_{\mu} - x_{\mu}\rvert < \eta$ and $\lvert u_{\mu} - x_{\mu}\rvert < \eta$, we have $\lvert f(x_{\mu}) - f(\ell_{\mu})\rvert \leqslant \frac{\varepsilon}{2m}$ and $\lvert f(x_{\mu}) - f(u_{\mu})\rvert \leqslant \frac{\varepsilon}{2m}$. Hence

$$\lvert f(\ell_{\mu}) - f(u_{\mu-1})\rvert \geqslant \lvert f(x_{\mu}) - f(x_{\mu-1})\rvert - 2\frac{\varepsilon}{2m}$$

for all $\mu$, and thus

$$V_{\pi}(f) \geqslant V_{\varsigma}(f) - \varepsilon$$

for all $\pi \in \mathfrak{T}_{[a,b]}$ with $\lvert \pi\rvert < \eta$. Therefore we have

$$\liminf_{n\to\infty} V_{\varsigma_n}(f) \geqslant V_{\varsigma}(f) - \varepsilon.$$

Since $\varepsilon > 0$ and $\varsigma \in \mathfrak{T}_{[a,b]}$ were arbitrary, it follows that

$$\liminf_{n\to\infty} V_{\varsigma_n}(f) \geqslant V_{[a,b]}(f).\tag{1}$$

Since

$$\limsup_{n\to\infty} V_{\varsigma_n}(f) \leqslant V_{[a,b]}(f)\tag{2}$$

is clear, we have

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} V_{\varsigma_n}(f) = V_{[a,b]}(f)\tag{3}$$

as desired.

Comment: Why do we've got $V_{\pi}(f) \geqslant \sum_{\mu = 1}^{m} \lvert f(\ell_{\mu}) - f(u_{\mu-1})\rvert$? And why $\lvert \ell_{\mu} - t_{\mu}\rvert < \eta$? Both claims are intuitively clear to me, but it seems to be complicated to prove them rigorously.

Comment: If $\ell_{\mu} = t_{i}$ and $u_{\mu-1} = t_{j}$, then we have $j < i$. Since $\eta$ is smaller than $\frac{1}{2}(x_{\mu} - x_{\mu-1})$, there are at least two partition points of $\pi$ between $x_{\mu-1}$ and $x_{\mu}$, say $x_{\mu-1} < t_c < t_{c+1} < x_{\mu}$. Then by definition $u_{\mu-1} \leqslant t_c$, and $\ell_{\mu} \geqslant t_{c+1}$, so $j \leqslant c < c+1 \leqslant i$. And $$\lvert f(\ell_{\mu}) - f(u_{\mu-1})\rvert = \lvert f(t_i) - f(t_j)\rvert \leqslant \lvert f(t_i) - f(t_{i-1})\rvert + \lvert f(t_{i-1})-f(t_{i-2})\rvert + \dotsc + \lvert f(t_{j+1}) - f(t_j)\rvert.$$ Add that up

Comment: for all $\mu$ to get $$\sum_{\mu = 1}^m \lvert f(\ell_{\mu}) - f(u_{\mu-1})\rvert \leqslant \sum_{\mu = 1}^m \sum_{u_{\mu-1} < t_{\rho} \leqslant \ell_{\mu}} \lvert f(t_{\rho}) - f(t_{\rho-1})\rvert \leqslant \sum_{\rho = 1}^r \lvert f(t_{\rho}) - f(t_{\rho-1})\rvert = V_{\pi}(f).$$ The $t_{\mu}$ was a typo, should have been $x_{\mu}$ (fixed now), and by definition of $\ell_{\mu}$ and $u_{\mu}$ we either have $\ell_{\mu} = u_{\mu} = x_{\mu}$, or $\ell_{\mu} < x_{\mu} < u_{\mu}$, and $u_{\mu} - \ell_{\mu} < \eta$ since $\ell_{\mu}$ and $u_{\mu}$ are successive points of $\pi$.

Comment: If $\mu\in\left\{1,\ldots,m\right\}$, then I only obtain $$x_{\mu-1}\le u_{\mu-1}\le x_\mu$$ and $$\ell_{\mu-1}\le x_{\mu-1}\le\ell_\mu$$ from the definitions, but that doesn't yield $u_{\mu-1}<\ell_\mu$. So, how do you obtain that?

Comment: As I wrote, there are at least two partition points of $\pi$ strictly between $x_{\mu-1}$ and $x_{\mu}$ since $\eta < \frac{1}{2}(x_{\mu} - x_{\mu-1})$, say $x_{\mu-1} < t_c < t_{c+1} < x_{\mu}$. Then $u_{\mu-1} \leqslant t_c$ and $t_{c+1} \leqslant \ell_{\mu}$. It wouldn't matter if we allowed $u_{\mu-1} = \ell_{\mu}$, for then the corresponding term in the sum would simply be $0$, but using the strict inequality in the choice of $\eta$ (or the constraint on $\lvert \pi\rvert$) rules that out.

Comment: I've got it now, but let me note following: The crucial point is that $(u_0,\ell_1,\ldots,u_{m-1},\ell_m)$ is a consecutive subsequence of $(t_0,\ldots,t_r)$ and that's all we need to conclude $V_{\pi}(f)\ge\sum_{\mu = 1}^{m} \lvert f(\ell_{\mu}) - f(u_{\mu-1})\rvert$. Moreover (I didn't see that at a first glance), your $\varepsilon$ is independent of $\eta$.

Comment: It's not in general consecutive, and it needn't be. We (possibly) drop some $\lvert f(t_{\rho}) - f(t_{\rho-1})\rvert$, and (possibly) replace some $$\lvert f(t_{\rho}) - f(t_{\rho-1})\rvert + \lvert f(t_{\rho+1}) - f(t_{\rho})\rvert + \dotsc + \lvert f(t_{\rho + j}) - f(t_{\rho + j - 1})\rvert$$ with the not-larger $\lvert f(t_{\rho + j}) - f(t_{\rho-1})\rvert = \lvert f(\ell_{\mu}) - f(u_{\mu-1})\rvert$. Thus the sum is not larger than $V_{\pi}(f)$. And indeed it is essential to have $\varepsilon$ independent of $\eta$, in fact $\eta$ depends on $\varepsilon$.

Comment: You could define $\tilde\eta:=\frac{1}{2} \min \{ x_k - x_{k-1} : 1 \leqslant k \leqslant m\}$. Then the statement is still valid for all $\tau\in\mathfrak T_{[a,\:b]}$ with $|\tau|<\tilde\eta$ and $\tilde\eta$ doesn't depend on $\varepsilon>0$ (just the later $\eta\in(0,\tilde\eta]$ from the uniform continuity does depend on $\varepsilon$, but that doesn't matter). And the sequence *is* consecutive (not strictly, maybe that's what you mean) in the sense of $u_{i-1}<\ell_i\le u_i$ for all $i\in\left\{1,\ldots,m\right\}$.

Comment: Ah, yes, that $u_{i-1} \leqslant \ell_i \leqslant u_i$ is important, yes (it's not essential that $u_{i-1}$ is _strictly_ smaller than $\ell_i$, however). I don't know the correct term for that either, but consecutive means (direkt) aufeinanderfolgend, as far as I recall.

Comment: It seems like you're right, we don't need that $u_{i-1}$ is *strictly* smaller than $\ell_i$. But then, we neither need that $\left|\left\{t_0,\ldots,t_r\right\}\cap(s_{i-1},s_i)\right|\ge2$. Or am I missing something? The only place where we need the latter fact is to obtain $u_{i-1}<\ell_i$.

Comment: Oh, and wouldn't we need $\liminf_{n\to\infty} V_{\varsigma_n}(f)\color{red}{>}V_{\varsigma}(f) - \varepsilon$ in order to conclude $\liminf_{n\to\infty} V_{\varsigma_n}(f) \geqslant V_{[a,\:b]}(f)$? (With $a\le b\Leftrightarrow \forall\varepsilon>0:a<b+\varepsilon$ in mind)

Comment: Right, we don't _need_ to have at least two points of $\pi$ between any two points of $\varsigma$. But when I typed the answer, I didn't know how much I would exactly need, so I took something simple that was certain to be sufficient to obtain the conclusion. So we have $u_{\mu-1} < \ell_{\mu}$, and that saves us the pixels needed to say that the term $\lvert f(\ell_{\mu}) - f(u_{\mu-1})\rvert$ might be redundant. Well. And $\geqslant V_{\varsigma}(f) - \varepsilon$ suffices, since $$(\forall\varepsilon > 0)(a < b+\varepsilon) \iff (\forall\varepsilon>0)(a\leqslant b+\varepsilon).$$